# Postgres cannot rename table because of AccessExcusiveLock

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to rename table. But it had error:

```
LOG:  sending cancel to blocking autovacuum PID 11911
Detail:  Process 10377 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on database 21819191 relation 24338310
Statement:  ALTER TABLE member_orderinfo2 RENAME TO member_orderinfo
```

Please tell me how to fix it ?
Thanks you !

Answer (score 1):

It is not error - it is log message so your request sent (and maybe still waits) cancel request to autovacuum. It is usually not any issue. Vacuum should be finished in next iteration.

Comment: Is there anyway to overcome this case ???

Comment: just try later and rename the table.